# If she were... would have coped

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions

I was supposed to fill the blank without changing a meaning of the first sentence.

She is not self-confident enough; that’s why she did not cope with the situation then.

If she were more self-confident, she ______________________ with the situation then.

My answer was "would cope", but according to the answer key it should be "would have coped". But I don't see why. We have here "If she were", so I thought it should be "would cope". If there were "If she had been", then I would choose "would have coped".

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"more confident" is being viewed as a persistent state. In indicative sentences, the present tense is used for states that persistently are true. For instance, "pentagons have fives sides" doesn't merely mean "pentagons currently have fives sides". If I were discussing an interaction with a  pentagon that occurred in the past, I would still use the present tense to refer to the pentagon having three sides, because that is a state that is not confined to the past.

Similarly, the [first conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional) is used when discussing conditions that refer to a persistent state that is not confined to a particular time period, even if its relevance applies to past period. For instance, "If pentagons had six sides, then it wouldn't have made sense that people called the military headquarters The Pentagon." Here, "called the military headquarters The Pentagon" is something that happened in the past, but pentagons having a particular number of sides is not confined to a particular period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Some grammar books suggest that there are 3(-4) possible structures.-> 1st, 2nd and 3rd conditionals. Some add the zero conditional. This is misleading. Any combination is possible.

You usually use **past simple + if** to talk about ***the present*** (or future).

> **If** she **were** more self-confident,...
>    (But she ***is*** not self-confident.)

You usually use **would(n't) have + past participle** to talk about something that happened/didn't happen in ***the past***. These things would(n't) have happened, if things were different in the if half of the sentence.

> …, she **would have coped** with the situation ***then***. (But she ***didn't cope*** with the situation.)

You usually use **would(n't)** to talk about something that isn't possible in ***the present***. These things would(n't) happen, if things in the if half of the sentence came true, which isn't possible now.

> …, she **would cope** with the situation. (But she ***can't cope*** with the situation now.)

So the following sentence is correct:

> If she **were** more self-confident, she **would have coped** with the situation ***then***.

= She ***is*** not self-confident, therefore she (***wasn't*** able to cope) /***didn't cope*** with the situation.

The following sentence is correct if you leave out ***then***::

> If she **were** more self-confident, she **would cope** with the situation.

= She ***is*** not self-confident, therefore she ***can't cope*** with the situation (now).

Comment: If she had been self-confident,she would have coped [etc].

Comment: If you use "If she had been self-confident …" you are talking about  a state that "was". If you use "If she were self-confident … " you are talking about a state that "is".

Comment: I'm saying it is missing from your sentences. If you give: would have coped, this is another ***possibility***

Answer (score 0):

In the example sentence, "were" is modified by the final "then" to express a hypothetical past condition, thus here "If she were" is equivalent to "If she had been".

Without the final "then" your answer of "would cope" would be correct, because the sentence would be expressing a hypothetical future condition.